# Compute probability of a grouping being correct

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, variance, unsupervised-learning

I have an exemplar grouping of objects (each with their own feature vector) into categories. I am then given a new grouping of compeltely different objects, and Iw would like to compute the probability of this grouping being 'correct'.

I realise this is a tricky problem, so I have tried to break it down a little.

My plan so far is to:

- For the training grouping, compute the mean variance of each feature within each cluster.
- Next, re-assign the training groups into random clusters, and again compute the mean variance of each feature.
- This should allow me to compute the probability of an unseen clustering being a true clustering, by comparing the variance of each feature with those in the 'true' and 'random' training examples

Does this sound like a sensible method? I am a little wary of the concept of taking means of variances.

Comment: You say you want to compute "the probability of this grouping being correct". By "correct" do you mean that it will naturally be separated from the rest of the data in an unsupervised sense (i.e. it will be a cluster)?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I suppose there are two elements to this problem - clusters being entities within themselves, and also clusters being well-separated from each other. I suppose I could treat each of these problems separately.

Comment: Actually I think well-separated is the only criterion. "Being entities" means you are assuming that they are supposed to have some type of distribution (e.g. Gaussian), if I understand correctly. Do you really expect clusters to have a specific distribution?

Comment: I suppose it depends on the assumptions made about the underlying data. I agree on the separation though. I think I really need a test for each, so that a split/merge operation can be evaluated for the change in overall likelihood.

Comment: It might go on forever, you need to have optimization schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I should say that evaluating whether data is "really" clustered is in general impossible because there are many definitions of what "good" clustering is and they usually make some assumptions about the distribution of each cluster, which is something that you don't have information about (otherwise you would have fit these specific distributions). Also, it doesn't make sense getting a probability as output unless you are assuming something about the distributions.

That being said, there are several such measures of "good" clustering, you can see some [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#Evaluation_of_clustering_results).

Regarding you method, the way see it is like this: You have in mind some statistics for each cluster, and you want to see how those statistics change if you add your new data. If they change "significantly", you say that you have a correct grouping.

I think this approach is ok, just realize its limitations:

1. The choice of statistics is everything and will change your results
   drastically. Make sure you understand what your statistic captures.
2. By using a certain statistic you are assuming something about the
   distribution of your clusters.
3. Imagine that only 10% of your data is really "separated". The statistics might change significantly but is your data truly a new group? How about if only one object in it is separated? What if it contains two groups that are very distant from each others?
4. Specifically regarding the variance, I think that is not a good statistic. I you meant the mean AND variance, this would be similar to doing a T-test for each feature. That is reasonable but it then means you are assuming a Gaussian distribution of each cluster. You might also consider statistics that are robust to outliers such as the median, to avoid extreme outlier effects as I proposed in (3). Think of it as if you are doing a statistical test for each feature - what do you want your test to be (e.g. parametric/non-parametric)?
5. If you are trying to determine significance by looking at the p-values of all tests, don't forget to do multiple hypothesis correction.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is no true measurement of clustering quality.

The problem is that by the very nature of the clustering task, you use clustering to find something *new* on your data. You do *not* use it to minimize a mathematical measure such as variance (which btw. heavily depends on the data set and normalization, and is sensitive to e.g. the number of clusters).

I see the strong risk in your approach that you **might not measure whether it is a true clustering or not, but whether it is a variance-optimized clustering**. So you might be able to say whether this was generated by k-means or not, but you might consider a non-k-means-clustering to be invalid.

You *really* need to be careful to *not overfit* your method to particular clustering concepts and algorithms (and in particular, not to k-means).